# HTML select tag not updating on change

Tags: javascript, html

I'm dynamically creating a select dropdown inside an html table with javascript. The html generated looks fine, but when i select an option nothing changes(the value is being updated, but the html still renders the first option).

```js
const reneArticleOptions = [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d",
    "e",
];

const cells = tr.children;


const sel = document.createElement("select");
sel.classList.add("custom-select");
sel.classList.add("mr-sm-2");
const option = document.createElement("option");
option.innerHTML = "Choose...";
sel.appendChild(option);
for(const reneArticleOption of reneArticleOptions) {
    const option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = reneArticleOption;
    sel.appendChild(option);
}
cells[1].replaceChild(sel, cells[1].childNodes[0]);
```

The select gets inserted into the `<td>` tag, but when i try to use it, the text doesn't update.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: I think we'll need to see a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem to be able to help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken the example code from your question and removed some of the bloat.
However, I cannot reproduce the problem, which means the problem isn't located in the code you've added.

```js
const reneArticleOptions = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

const sel = document.createElement("select");

const option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = "Choose...";
sel.appendChild(option);

for(const reneArticleOption of reneArticleOptions) {
    const option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = reneArticleOption;
    sel.appendChild(option);
}

document.body.appendChild(sel);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28243877)

Comment: @Logemann I can totally understand where you're coming from and partly I do agree. However, one thing that is on my mind is that converting the above code to a snippet does have an added value, but at the same time, I don't want to edit the question as it causes confusion. The confusion would be caused by the fact that the edit proves that there's a problem with the question. I would normally add a comment, but since I can't add snippets to comments, I decided to write an answer instead. But yes, in this sense the only "thing" it answers is that the code in the above question is not broken.